# How to find $\int_{S^2}f \cdot n \ \text{d}S$ if $f(x,y,z):=(x^3,y^3,z^3)^T$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

With $\mathbb{S}^2$ being the unit sphere, how to find

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2} \vec{f} \cdot \vec{n} \ \text{d}S$$

if $\vec{f}(x,y,z):=(x^3,y^3,z^3)^T$?

Apparently, we need to use Gauss. With $B$ being the unit ball we get:

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2} \vec{f} \cdot \vec{n} \ \text{d}S = \int\limits_B \operatorname{div} \vec{f} \ \text{d}V$$

with $\operatorname{div}f=3x^2+3y^2+3z^2$.

Yet I'm not quite sure how to move further. I've tried the transformation theorem:

$$\int_{\phi(K)} f = \int_{K} f(\phi(x)) |\det \phi'(x)| \ \text{d}x$$
with $\phi(r,\alpha,\beta):=(r \cos\alpha, r \sin\alpha \cos\beta, r \sin\alpha \sin\beta)$ and got stuck right away.

Comment: You can easily integrate $g(x,y,z)=3x^2+3y^2+3z^2$ over the ball by using spherical coordinates together with the fact that $g$ is invariant under rotations. You will get something in terms of the surface area of the sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\operatorname{div} \vec{f} = 3x^2+3y^2+3z^2$, which in spherical coordinates

$$
\begin{align}
x & = r \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \\
y & = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \\
z & = r \cos \varphi,
\end{align}
$$

for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $0 \leq \varphi \leq \pi$, becomes $\operatorname{div} \vec{f} = 3 r^2.$

Therefore, using Gauss's Theorem we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2} \vec{f} \cdot \vec{n} \, \text{d}S & = \int\limits_{B} \operatorname{div} \vec{f} \, \text{d}V \\
 & = \int_0^{2\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \int_0^1 (3r^2) \cdot (r^2 \sin \varphi) \, \text{d} r \, \text{d} \varphi \, \text{d} \theta \\
 & = 3 \int_0^{2\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \text{d} \theta \int_0^{\pi} \hspace{-5pt} \sin \varphi \, \text{d} \varphi \int_0^1 \hspace{-3pt} r^4 \, \text{d} r \\
 & = \frac{12 \pi}{5}.
\end{align}
$$

**Edit:** Elaborating as the OP asked, we have

$$\operatorname{div} \vec{f} = 3x^2+3y^2+3z^2 =3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

in cartesian coordinates. When we apply the spherical coordinate changes we have

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2,$$

therefore

$$\operatorname{div} \vec{f} = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 3r^2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please elaborate how did you get $3r^2$, this is where I got stuck.

Comment: @mathusiast Done! =) If you feel you still don't get it let me know.